# Angular library created by CLI doesn't get auto import suggestion. Final bundle js file included double Angular code

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

TL;DR

Source code: https://github.com/trungk18/multiple-projects

I used CLI to create Angular library and consume it from another Angular application. But there was three problems.

1. Why the auto suggestion for the library doesn't work?
2. The language service for templating suggestion doesn't work too, what would be wrong?
3. How to exclude Angular's code from the library?

---

So, I am following this [guide](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) to create shared library for our client side application. My plan is to create multiple library modules in the same Angular CLI application name **angular-lib**. For instance,

1. A module that provide all the component and pipe for displaying Date Time
2. A module that all the component and pipe for displaying a loading indicator
3. And so on, you named it.

I created these two mentioned libraries using the following command.

```
ng new angular-lib --create-application=false
cd angular-lib
ng generate library date-time 
ng generate library loading-indicator
```

The two public modules from these library will be

- DateTimeModule
- LoadingIndicatorModule

I build the two libraries using

```
ng build date-time
ng build loading-indicator
```

The dist folder was generated nicely with all the necessary bundles and types.

---

I also created two application using `ng new` command.

- ng new main
- ng new main2

Ideally, each of them will be a standalone Angular application and will consume the library that I have just created. The folder structure was displayed as the below photo. Noticed that **angular-lib**, **main** and **main2** application were in the same parents folder **multiple-projects**

*You can check the **[source code](https://github.com/trungk18/multiple-projects) for more detail***

[image: Imgur]

I go ahead to main application, install the **angular-lib** locally using this command (relative path). We don't have a plan to publish the package to npm so I wanted to test locally first.

```
npm install ..\angular-lib\ --save
```

It got installed nicely, the `package.json` was updated too.

```
{
  "name": "main",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",    
    "angular-lib": "file:../angular-lib"
  }
}
```

**The problems was appeared from there.**

**1.** I went ahead to `app.module.ts` to import my `DateTimeModule` library. I entered DateTime and do Ctrl + Space on VSCode, but there was no suggestions at all. Even when I typed full name `DateTimeModule`, still no importing suggestion.

[image: Imgur]

However, when I tried to import manually with the path to `angular-lib/dist/datetime`, VSCode found the module.

[image: Imgur]

I did try to configure the paths on `tsconfig.json` but no luck.

**What could be wrong here? Do I need to do any extra steps to get the suggestion done?**

Because I thought Typescript will try to find all the d.ts and let me looks for them. But apparently, It didn't

**2.** After manually import the module, I was trying to use the component on the template. But also, the language service wasn't be able to find my library somehow.

[image: Imgur]

**So I have the same question as above. What can I do to make it work?**

**3.** Ok fair enough, there could be something wrong but the build went successfully. I open the application, the lib component was loaded as expected. But I noticed the bundle size of my application was increased from 3.7mb to 5.3mb.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

By using source map explorer, I saw the Angular's code was also included in my library. **How would I be able to only import the library code from another Angular project, but exclude the Angular code?**

I followed the instruction to bring all the library dependencies to devDependencies but there are no different. The [CLI guide](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) seems to be valid when you have all your projects in a single application. *But for us, there are multiple standalone client side application. So that we have to split the common shared library to be a stand alone module that the other app can consume.*

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run `npm install ../angular-lib/ --save` to install your libs.

Because this will copy the `angular-lib/node_modules` file to `main/node_modules/angular-lib/node_modules`, this is the reason why you have two angular modules in your bundle file.

There are 3 ways to do the same thing, you can choose one that you like:

**1. npm install [local/paths].tgz**

Run the following command to pack your library.

```sh
$ cd angular-lib/dist/date-time
$ npm pack
```

Install the pack in your main project.

```
$ cd main
$ npm i ../angular-lib/dist/date-time/date-time-0.0.1.tgz
```

**2. npm link**

Run the following command to link your library.

```
$ cd angular-lib/dist/date-time
$ npm link
```

Link it in the main project.

```
$ cd main
$ npm link date-time
```

**3. config paths**

Add the following configuration in your `main/tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
    "paths": {
      "date-time": ["../angular-lib/dist/date-time/"],
      "date-time/*": ["../angular-lib/dist/date-time/*"]
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
...
import { DateTimeModule } from 'date-time';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    DateTimeModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks Lee, the first approach worked for me. The auto import for DateTimeModule still doesn't work, I will spend times on that. I have a few questions. 1. Are there any quick way to build and pack all the projects? 2. If I want to package all the library inside a same angular-lib, and when install from npm. I want to do something like `npm i ../angular-lib-0.0.1.tgz` with all the libraries. And I can do import like `import {DateTimeModule} from 'angular-lib/date-time'`. How would I do? Because the angular-lib folder currently has it own package.json and everything. I was a bit confused.